# How to select patches based on the same variable value in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

When one variable of a patch reaches a certain value (e.g. `age = 75` ), I redirect the patch to another procedure (called  `retirement`) where I want to select all the patches that share the same value of the variable `Farm_ID` so the procedure is applied to all the patches.

I'm looking for a command which mean "the same as", I also considered to use the `to-report` and  `report` procedure to report the `pxcor` and `pycor` of the original patch and then ask the other patches with the same ID_Farm as the `patch pxcor pycor`
But I feel like I'm missing something in the essence of using Netlogo (I'm a newbie).

```
to start-simulation
  reset-timer
  tick-advance 70
;; increase the farmer's age
 ask patches with [seed = 1] [set age age + 1]
 
  ask patches [
    if age = 75 [ retirement ]
  ]
;; other stuffs
end

to retirement
   ask patches with [ ID_Farm = ???]
;; procedure to change the variable ID_Farm depending on the closest patches with a different ID_Farm
end
```

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer. However, in the future please make sure to provide a [mre]. You should post some complete piece of code (but the shortest possible) such that those who read your question are able to reproduce the exact problem you are having by just copying and pasting what you provide. This makes life a lot easier for those who try to help you, and it makes it more likely for you to receive relevant answers

Comment: Hi Matteo, thank you for your answer which was very useful and taught me about ```myself``` command which does the job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `myself` (see [here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#myself)), and more specifically you need to use `variable = [variable] of myself`.

See a minimal and reproducible example below:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  
  ask patches [
    ifelse (pxcor > 0)
      [set pcolor lime]
      [set pcolor orange]
  ]
end

to go
  ask one-of patches [
    type "I am the chosen patch. My color is " type (ifelse-value (pcolor = 25) ["orange"] (pcolor = 65) ["lime"] ["cyan"]) print ". I and all patches having my same color will become cyan."    
    operate-on-patches-with-my-same-color
  ]
end

to operate-on-patches-with-my-same-color
  ask patches with [pcolor = [pcolor] of myself] [
    set pcolor cyan
  ]
end
```

---

When you check the `myself` entry in the NetLogo Dictionary, note the difference between `self` and `myself`. At the beginning it may be confusing, but as you get more and more used with how NetLogo works it will become clear.